# Transferring Data from Salesforce to other Tool

Tags: integration, data-loader

Is there any way I can transfer my data from Salesforce to other tool(like ALM).

I know that Dataloader can be used, but My problem is mainly with the documents(word,ppt,images etc.) associated with the records.How will I extract them?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you explain what "ALM" is?

Comment: ALM(Application Life Management) is a tool to store your project related information during the entire SDLC phase.(Right from requirements,design to testing).

Comment: Is this it http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/app-lifecycle-management-vs.aspx? Please provide a link. Or are you talking more about a concept than a specific tool?

Comment: It is HP's ALM tool.(http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/application-lifecycle-management.html).We are planning to move the information stored as records and their attachments in salesforce(Requirements and their associated design documents,Training Materials etc) to ALM tool/Sharepoint.Let say I have "REQ-001" as a record and it has 1 Requirement Word doc and  1 Design PPT attached.The key point I would like to know is how will I extract them from salesforce such that I can easily differentiate which attachment belongs to which requirement/ record. Many thanks.

Comment: Attachments have a ParentId field (see JSON below) which is the ID of the object they are attached to. So you can query to find the IDs of your records, and then query for the attachments "... from Attachment where ParentId in :recordIds".

Answer (score 3):

This assumes you don't mind writing code to do this and that you mean Attachments (as you mention the documents being associated with records).

You can use the [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf) (from whatever programming language you prefer) to first obtain JSON describing the attachments via a URL such as:

```
/services/data/v23.0/query?q=select+...+from+Attachment+where+...
```

that returns:

```
{
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "Body": "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00PF000000AFDNiMAP/Body",
      "ContentType": "application/msword",
      "Description": null,
      "Id": "00PF000000AFDNiMAP",
      "IsPrivate": false,
      "Name": "Sample Death Certificate.doc",
      "OwnerId": "005A00000015yZUIAY",
      "ParentId": "a0YF0000001otNDMAY",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Attachment",
        "url": "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00PF000000AFDNiMAP"
      }
    }],
  "totalSize": 1
}
```

The URL to obtain the binary data for each Attachment is provided in the "Body" field. So e.g. in Java a [commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) GET request using that URL and writing the data to a file would look like this:

```
public void readBytes(String relativeUrl, File file) throws Exception {
    GetMethod get = createGet(instanceUrl + relativeUrl);
    try {
        client.executeMethod(get);
        if (get.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            InputStream is = get.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            try {
                int length;
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            } finally {
                os.close();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(""
                    + "status=" + get.getStatusLine().toString()
                    + " response body=" + get.getResponseBodyAsString()
                    + " for query get=" + get
                    );
        }
    } finally {
        get.releaseConnection();
    }
}
private GetMethod createGet(String uri) {
    GetMethod get = new GetMethod(uri);
    get.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + sessionId);
    return get;
}
```

Or if the target system also supports web service interfaces you could write the data straight to that system without ever creating a file.